# How can I math a regular expression to write an htaccess rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want this URL

http://rebateninja.com/index.php?page=home

To be previewed like this via htaccess

http://rebateninja.com/home

I know it is not that hard and I have done that before, but for some reason it is not working now at all. My .htaccess contains the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (index.php\?page=)(.*) /$2 [NC,R=301,L]
```

What I am doing wrong? Perhaps it is related to my Apache version? I have lost my entire morning without success!!! Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't match against the query string in a `RewriteRule`, you need to use a `RewriteCond` with either `%{THE_REQUEST}` or `%{QUERY_STRING}` and use a **%** to backreference groupings:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /index\.php\?page=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule /%2? [L,R=301]
```

That externally redirects the browser so that the URL in the address bar changes. In order to internally rewrite it back you need to do:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.phjp?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
RewriteRule ^index.php\?page=(.*)$ /$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```